# Importing npm/node.js packages to snel

Tags: import, components, svelte, deno

While exploring 'snel' a compiler for svelte applications, I came across an issue when trying to import remote svelte components

I got the following error, uppon trying to import components.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'svelte')
    at Object.resolveId (https://deno.land/x/snel@v0.6.0/src/shared/bundler.js:57:37)
    at https://unpkg.com/rollup@2.58.0/dist/es/rollup@2.58.0/dist/es/rollup.browser.js:11:370111
```

I did not find any similar problem or could not find out why this import statement would not work.
So I wondered how I can import external components for svelte using deno and snel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging I was able to resolve this issue by reading more about how deno works.
I now understand that in deno, and thus in snel, to use npm/node.js svelte packages, you need use CDNs to import something, as shown in the [deno manual](https://deno.land/manual@v1.12.2/npm_nodejs/cdns)

I resolved my issue, by using a CDN inside of the following import statement

```js
import * as L from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/leaflet';
```

You can also use it in an import map as shown in the [snel documentation](https://deno.land/x/snel@v0.6.0)